# IIS not displaying feature "Server Certificates"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl, iis-7, iis-7.5

I am looking for a solution to a feature not displaying in the IIS Manager (Version 7.5). 
Currently, I am not able to view the "Server Certificates" Feature (which is visible in other machines I have running 7.5 IIS.

The machine that is hosting the IIS manager is connected to remotely, but I dont think this impacts whether or not "Server Certificates" displays or not.

Someone told me that it might have to do with the version of IIS, but I dont think that is the case.

Anyone know why IIS manager , when connecting to another machine from the connections left pane, would not display Server Certificates??

I searched but could find a fix. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Server certificates can only be managed locally so IIS Manager does not show that page if you manage a remote server.

Comment: Thank you Lex. I can partially validate your claim because for each and every environment, I cannot see this feature on any other server except for my local server. It looks like I will have to instead remote into the server directly instead of using IIS manager from a remote machine to connect. Ill test this out. Thank you.